# How to draw sector ( Quarter Circle) in windows phone dynamically?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I want to draw the Shape as in the image. [image: arc or halfcircle] [image: Sector or Quarter circle]I have drawn half circle using Arc Segment, Now I want to draw Quarter circle, or A Sector, But I am unable to draw it.

I used this code to draw Arc, I tried to change the size, and the angle is also not working.

What should I do to draw Quarter circle / Sector ?? Code I used to draw Arc is :

```
PathFigure pthFigure1 = new PathFigure();
pthFigure1.StartPoint = new Point(50, 60);// starting cordinates of arcs
ArcSegment arcSeg1 = new ArcSegment();
arcSeg1.Point = new Point(100, 82);   // ending cordinates of arcs
arcSeg1.Size = new Size(10, 10);

arcSeg1.IsLargeArc = false;
arcSeg1.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
arcSeg1.RotationAngle = 90;
PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection1 = new PathSegmentCollection();
myPathSegmentCollection1.Add(arcSeg1);
pthFigure1.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection1;
PathFigureCollection pthFigureCollection1 = new PathFigureCollection();
pthFigureCollection1.Add(pthFigure1);
PathGeometry pthGeometry1 = new PathGeometry();
pthGeometry1.Figures = pthFigureCollection1;
System.Windows.Shapes.Path arcPath1 = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
arcPath1.Data = pthGeometry1;
arcPath1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 23, 0));
this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(arcPath1);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With minimum changes to your code (`/**/` signifies changed or added lines).

```
PathFigure pthFigure1 = new PathFigure();
/**/ pthFigure1.StartPoint = new Point(0, 100);// starting cordinates of arcs
ArcSegment arcSeg1 = new ArcSegment();
/**/ arcSeg1.Point = new Point(100, 0);   // ending cordinates of arcs
/**/ arcSeg1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
arcSeg1.IsLargeArc = false;
arcSeg1.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
/**/ LineSegment lineSeg = new LineSegment();
/**/ lineSeg.Point = new Point(100,100);
PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection1 = new PathSegmentCollection();
myPathSegmentCollection1.Add(arcSeg1);
/**/ myPathSegmentCollection1.Add(lineSeg);
pthFigure1.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection1;
PathFigureCollection pthFigureCollection1 = new PathFigureCollection();
pthFigureCollection1.Add(pthFigure1);
...
```

It seems that you missinterpret the meaning of `ArcSegment.RotationAngle`.

The math of it:

[image]